# Initialize the jQuery plugin after AJAX content loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, plugins, modal-dialog

I'm using the PopEasy jQuery plugin to pop up modal forms. I have it working if the trigger links and the DIV containing the modal form are in the main document which uses

```
$(document).ready(function(){...
```

to initialize the plugin.

But, I need to trigger the modal from content which is loaded via AJAX, which happens *after* the main document is "ready".

I've tried

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){...
```

but I might be using AJAX in a slightly different way than that method expects?

How can I initialize the plugin after the AJAX content loads?

Comment: Note that `$(document).ajaxComplete` is called after _every_ completed AJAX request. So if you have (potentially) more than one AJAX call, your code is (potentially) executed multiple times. You just want to use the `success` callback of the AJAX call that loads _this_ specific content, as in Murali's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure in a `success callback` once the content were retreived

```
$.ajax({
  url:"server.aspx",
  type:"POST",
   success:function(result){
   //do it here
   }
});
```

Comment: There seems to be many ways to do AJAX. The one that I'm familiar with uses GetXmlHttpObject, and .onreadystatechange, .readystate, .status, .responseText, .open and .send. I've tried at the end of the function assigned to .onreadystatechange but it didn't work, but with js, it's hard for me to tell why something doesn't work. I don't know js very well.

`test`

Comment: There seems to be many ways to do AJAX. The one that I'm familiar with is below. I've tried the plugin after the innerHTML line but it didn't work. But with js, it's hard for me to tell why something doesn't work. I don't know js very well. How would I implement your answer?


`function getClassListAjax()
  {
  x= GetXmlHttpObject();
  x.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
    if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200)
      { document.getElementById("cla").innerHTML = x.responseText; }
    }
    x.open("POST", "ajax.php", true);
    x.send(null);
  }`

Comment: oh, that was jQuery AJAX. I'll try converting over to it and see how it goes.

Comment: OK, I converted to the jQuery AJAX and put the modal plugin code in the success: parameter after the AJAX data was written to the DOM and it worked like a charm. Thanks!